# Using onclick event for play framwork scala template

Tags: javascript, playframework

I want to implement some simple client side functionality into my play application. I have a checkbox which, when ticked, I want a html div to be displayed.
Here is my checkbox scala/html

```
@checkbox(
                plotDetailForm("plantingFlag"),
                '_label -> "Planting plot",
                '_onclick -> "javascript:togglePlanting('block');"
            )
```

When this renders in the browser, the onclick is not included. This is the source:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="plantingFlag" name="plantingFlag" value="true" checked >
```

I would like to know I can have a client side onclick with my @checkbox

Comment: Dont you use jQuery in your play project ?

Comment: Yeah I have Jquery implemented with twitter bootstrap. Not actively using it though I suppose. Can I use that? Not up on Jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the argument without underscore:

```
@checkbox(
    plotDetailForm("plantingFlag"),
    '_label -> "Planting plot",
    'onclick -> "javascript:togglePlanting('block');",
    'foo -> "bar"
)
```

As stated in the [docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0/JavaFormHelpers):

> **Note:** All extra parameters will be added to the generated HTML, except for ones whose name starts with the _ character. Arguments starting with an underscore are reserved for field constructor argument (which we will see later).

Answer (score 3):

The way to write Javascript for a Play! template is to import an external file.

See http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Assets

For your feature, this external file should contain :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    initCheckbox();
});

function initCheckbox(){
    $('#plantingFlag').change(function(){
        console.log("toggle");
        togglePlanting('block');
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. I don't have it working though

I have the script

<script href="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/toggle.js")" type="javascript"></script>

and I have put you code into the file toggle.js. All other code is left the same. Not happening in the browser

Comment: I edited the code to make it cleaner, and to remove the condition on the checkbox to be checked. If it doesnt work, what's happens in your JS console ?

Comment: I have firebug (not used to using it). I noticed it could not see the javascript asset so I changed to script tag to: <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/toggle.js")"></script> . The script (your new one) is now visible in firebug. I have never used JS console. The toggle is still not working. Could you elaborate on what I could see with JS console? I need to get it

Comment: I added a console log in the see , see my edit. You should see it

Comment: ReferenceError: togglePlanting is not defined

togglePlanting('block');

Comment: I don't have the togglePlanting() function anymore :) could you repost

Comment: Replace with any javascript you want to be executed !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both you guys for posting. I final have it working. Omitting the _ underscore is what I needed. This way of calling javascripts makes more immediate sense to me.

I ended up with first a external script declaration:

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/toggle.js")"></script>
```

The javascript (toogle.js), which first checks the state of the checkbox on page ready and sets the divs viability accordingly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var c = document.getElementById("plantingFlag");
if(c.checked == 1){
    document.getElementById("block").style.display = 'block';
} else{
    document.getElementById("block").style.display = 'none';
}
});

function toggle_visibility(id) {
var e = document.getElementById(id);
if(e.style.display == 'block')
    e.style.display = 'none';
else
    e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

And finally checkbox

```
@checkbox(
                plotDetailForm("plantingFlag"),
                '_label -> "Planting plot",
                'onclick -> "javascript:toggle_visibility('block');"
            )
```